# Android OpenCV - detect curves from Houghlines

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am writing an app using OpenCV 2.4.3.2 for Android.
my app is about license plate recognition.
there are a few ways to do it , I chose to do the following:
1. convert the image to HSV color space
2. threshold image according to license plate HSV (in my country they are yellow...)
3. smooth the image with a Gaussian Blur
4. Detect edges
5. find contours 
6. fund houghlines
7. from the houglines, detect curves that match rectangle
I am stuck at 7, I can't find a way to successfully detect the rectangles from the houglines.

I would very much appreciate a code sample in Java, since most of the examples are in C/C++ and converting it is not so straightforward.
here is my code (right now I am just drawing the lines...):

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame, mRGBMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);
// convert HSC color space
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRGBMat, mHSVMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
// Filter out colors which are out of range (license plate hue ~ 14)
            Core.inRange(mHSVMat, new Scalar(9, 70, 80, 0), new Scalar(30, 255,
                    255, 0), mGrayMat);
            // some smoothing of the image
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGrayMat, mGrayMat, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
            }
Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE,
                    new Size(3, 3), new Point(1, 1));
Imgproc.Canny(mGrayMat, mGrayMat0, 48, 120);
Imgproc.dilate(mGrayMat0, mGrayMat0, kernel);
kernel.release();
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new Vector<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(mGrayMat0, contours, mHirerchy,
                    Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            Mat lines = new Mat(); // finds houghlines in the contours
            Imgproc.HoughLinesP(mGrayMat0, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, 1);
            for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) {
                double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
                double x1 = vec[0], y1 = vec[1], x2 = vec[2], y2 = vec[3];
                Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
                Point end = new Point(x2, y2);
                Core.line(mRgba, start, end, RECT_COLOR, 1);

            }
```

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583649/opencv-c-rectangle-detection-which-has-irregular-side

Answer (score 0):

I've written such an algorithm before. You classify the lines into two types:
1) vertical
2) horizontal
x) outliers for deletion

Then you classify the lines more into two subtypes each:
1a) vertical, the left border
1b) vertical, the right border
1x) outliers for deletion
2a), 2b), 2x).

Get the average slopes and intercept points of these lines and you have your "rectangle".