# trying to detect a rectangle using find contours

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect a rectangle using find contours, but I don't get any contours from the following image.

I cant detect any contours in the image. Is find contours is bad with the following image, or should I use hough transform.

UPDATE: I have updated the source code to use approximated polygon.

but I still I get the outlier bounding rect, I cant find the smallest rectangle that is in the screenshot.

[image]

I have another case which the current solution it doesnt work even when adding erosion or dilation.

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dy6O.png)

and here is the code

```
using namespace cm;
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;


    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("heightmap.png");
    RNG rng(12345);
    // convert to grayscale (you could load as grayscale instead)
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(input,gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);


    // compute mask (you could use a simple threshold if the image is always as good as the one you provided)
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::threshold(gray, mask, 0, 255,CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    cv::namedWindow("threshold");
    cv::imshow("threshold",mask);

    // find contours (if always so easy to segment as your image, you could just add the black/rect pixels to a vector)
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::findContours(mask,contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    cv::Mat drawing = cv::Mat::zeros( mask.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > ( contours.size() );
    vector<cv::Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        approxPolyDP( cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect( cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
    }

     for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
        rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );

    }

    // display
    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("drawing", drawing);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using looks like its from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583649/opencv-c-rectangle-detection-which-has-irregular-side).

It uses `BinaryInv` threshold because its detecting a black shape on white background.

Your example is the opposite so you should tweak your code to use `Binary` threshold type instead (or negate the image).

Without this fix, `FindContours` will detect the *perimeter* of the image which will be the biggest contour.

So I don't think the code is failing to detect contours, just not the "biggest contour" you expect.

Even with that fixed, the code you posted won't fit a rectangle to the rectangle in your example image, as the most obvious rectangular feature doesn't have a clean border. The `approxPolyDP` suggestion in the linked question might help but you'll have to improve the source image.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260519/hough-transformation-vs-contour-detection-for-rectangle-recognition-with-perspec) for a comparison of this and Hough methods for finding rectangles.

**Edit**

You should be able to separate the rectangle in your example image from the other blob by calling `Erode` (3x3) twice.

You'll have to replace selecting the biggest contour with selecting the **squarest**.

Comment: so you think I should use hough transform instead of find contours ? because I have irregular shapes ?

Comment: Depends. If you can clean up the image stick with `findContours` as its more stable.

Comment: what do you mean clean up the image stick. Iḿ a beginner and Iḿ learning. please try to explain more and help me. thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry... should have been a comma there. If you can clean up the image then `findContours` will work better. Check the link at the end of my answer for a comparison of both methods.

Comment: how would I clean up the image ? using dilation and erosion ? is that what you mean ?

Comment: Eroding the image a couple of times will separate the rectangle from the other main feature for that example image. You might find that calling `approxPolyDP` with different "approximation accuracy" values is necessary to get an exactly 4 sided shape.

Comment: Thanks. Can you check the update question. I have a case where it fails recognizing the rectangle, and it considers it as a one big blob.